# How do I set a value of a nil field just before save in mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongoid model, say Webpage, which is like this:

```
class Webpage
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :short_link, type: String
  field :actual_link, type: String

  before_save :generate_short_link

  protected

  def generate_short_link
    short_link ||= rand(36**8).to_s(36)
  end
end
```

But when I do Webpage.create, the short_link is not automatically populated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to populate a short_link only on create and it is better to use `before_create` callback.

```
class Webpage
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :short_link, type: String
  field :actual_link, type: String

  before_create :generate_short_link

  protected

  def generate_short_link
    self.short_link = rand(36**8).to_s(36)
  end
end
```

Comment: is `self.short_link` the right accessor? I'm using just `short_link`.

Comment: `self` in current scope is an instance of Webpage and it's right accessor.

Comment: Yes, rails callbacks should be used here, as as default: value on Mongoid will not set the field if a nil value has been applied (e.g. from a factory method). I would. however, use the before_validation callback instead for the most part

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mongoid [docs for Callbacks](http://mongoid.org/docs/callbacks.html), it only fires the callback of the action you are executing. That is why it is not firing. You would need to do as Voldy answered, use the `before_create` callback.

However, if that is all the you are doing (your code is not more complicated), then instead of setting `short_link` if it was not assigned already, you could just set that as the default like this:

```
class Webpage
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :short_link,  type: String,  default: -> { rand(36**8).to_s(36) }
  field :actual_link, type: String

end
```

This will behave the same as your current code is intended to.

Comment: I tried Webpage.new followed by a save!. It still does not work. The callback is fired, but the short link field is not set. Is `short_link` the right accessor for the short_link field? I tried `self.short_link` and things worked, but self.short_link seems wrong to me.

Comment: You need `self.short_link` in general, but with my solution you don't have to worry about the callbacks. `Webpage.new` will create a new `Webpage`, with `short_link` either set by you during creation, or with the result of the lambda if you don't supply a value.

Comment: I meant `Webpage.create` instead of `Webpage.new`, was a little too tired last night.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit of a moron when it comes to callbacks, especially when it's something like "updating/setting a field before the object is saved". I found that using `before_validation` make these kind of errors go away, at least the few times I tried. Though I'd like at some point to understand why, what did I miss with regular callbacks & what did I do wrong.